# How to capture the URL of the 'about to' download file on a browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

I want to write a piece of code that triggers an event when a file is getting downloaded.
Lets say its a chrome extension.

Like a Download Manager intercepts the browser download process, captures the file URL and downloads it. I want to capture the URL of the files getting downloaded and avoid the browser download process.

Thanks for taking a look !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can detect a downloading event with [chrome.downloads.onCreated](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html#event-onCreated) listener and perevent it with [chrome.downloads.cancel method](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html#method-cancel).

But [chrome.downloads API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html) is expiremental and only works on [chrome dev channel version](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/index.html?extra=devchannel#eula) for now.

```
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function(DownloadItem downloadItem) {
   chrome.downloads.cancel(downloadItem.id , function() {
       console.log("Download was cancelled")
   });
});
```